# Moving an element on mousemove event fails when moving too fast (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm building an element which could be moved on mouse events.

Here's the code from an [example CodePen pen](https://codepen.io/kosarh79/pen/wqXGdE) I found on the internet. The general concept is: 1) get original cursor location on `mousedown`, 2) move the element on `mousemove`, 3) stop on `mouseleave` or `mouseup`.

```js
var offset = [0, 0];
var divOverlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var isDown = false;

divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
        divOverlay.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        divOverlay.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        divOverlay.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
        divOverlay.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" onm>
  ... some other stuff ...
  <img id="large" src="something.jpg" >
</div>
```

I used the same concept but with Vue.js. It works, but it's far from perfect. **If I move faster, the cursor somehow leaves the element, which ends the `mousemove` events.** I can't figure out what is wrong. [Here's my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aljohn0422/9hjm7c8u/16/).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blocks: [{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      active: false
    }],
    offsetX: undefined,
    offsetY: undefined,
  },
  methods: {
    mousedown(e, i) {
      this.blocks[i].active = true;
      this.offsetX = e.offsetX;
      this.offsetY = e.offsetY;
    },
    mouseup(i) {
      this.blocks[i].active = false;
    },
    mousemove(e, i) {
      if (this.blocks[i].active) {
        let x = e.offsetX;
        let y = e.offsetY;
        let dx = x - this.offsetX;
        let dy = y - this.offsetY;
        this.blocks[i].top += dy;
        this.blocks[i].left += dx;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div
    class="block" 
    v-for="(_, i) in blocks" 
    @mousedown="mousedown($event, i)" 
    @mousemove="mousemove($event, i)" 
    @mouseup="mouseup(i)" 
    @mouseleave="mouseup(i)" 
    :class="{ active: blocks[i].active }" 
    :style="{ top: blocks[i].top + 'px', left: blocks[i].left + 'px' }"></div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active {
  background: gray;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blocks: [{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      active: false
    }],
    offsetX: undefined,
    offsetY: undefined,
  },
  methods: {
    mousedown(e, i) {
      this.blocks[i].active = true;
      this.offsetX = e.offsetX;
      this.offsetY = e.offsetY;
    },
    mouseup(i) {
      this.blocks[i].active = false;
    },
    mousemove(e, i) {
      if (this.blocks[i].active) {
        let x = e.offsetX;
        let y = e.offsetY;
        let dx = x - this.offsetX;
        let dy = y - this.offsetY;
        this.blocks[i].top += dy;
        this.blocks[i].left += dx;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
    class="block" 
    v-for="(_, i) in blocks" 
    @mousedown="mousedown($event, i)" 
    @mousemove="mousemove($event, i)" 
    @mouseup="mouseup(i)" 
    @mouseleave="mouseup(i)" 
    :class="{ active: blocks[i].active }" 
    :style="{ top: blocks[i].top + 'px', left: blocks[i].left + 'px' }"></div>
</div>
```

How should I modify my code so that it works as well as the pure JavaScript version?

Comment: Add mousemove and mouseup on document instead of that element. Only mousedown should be on the element you want to move.

Comment: By doing so I managed to solve the problem. Thanks! But could you explain a bit? I looked up some article but couldn't find anything. In this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) however, all mouse events were added to the `element`, rather than `document`.

Comment: As you've guessed, you move mouse cursor out of the elements box before the DOM can rerender, so your `mousemove` event now targets the element under the one you want to target. So it just stops working correctly. Adding `mousemove` and `mouseup` listeners to the element is not a good choice.

Comment: One more thing, you should add `mousemove` and `mouseup` listeners on the `document/window` only after you `mousedown` otherwise the listeners will listen all the time for no reason and it can affect performance. Not by much, but still...

Comment: If you look at your JS example, it is using the `document`. You haven't shared all of your Vue code (template, etc.), so we can't actually see where you're attaching your event handlers in that.

Comment: Please note: your JSFiddle needs to be modified to have Vue as the framework, not just as the language. Otherwise you get `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#66:1'>66:1</a> Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor"` when running it.

Comment: Also, you say part of the concept is to "finish on `mouseleave`," but that never appears in the JS demo.